# Convert Encode string value to PDF-417 barcode in Windows 8 application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, barcode, zxing

I am trying to convert string value to PDF-417 barcode format using ZXing https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ in Windows 8 application. Currently I am able to write only below code how can I put BitMatrix to image source.

```
        int width = 115;
        int Height = 65;

        PDF417Writer writer = new PDF417Writer();
        BitMatrix bitIMGNew = writer.encode(value, BarcodeFormat.PDF_417, width, Height);
        WriteableBitmap imgBitmap = bitIMGNew.ToBitmap();
```

How can I achieve this? Or Do I need to use any other dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a PDF417 code from some content with ZXing.Net you should try the following snippet:

```
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
   Format = BarcodeFormat.PDF_417,
   Options = new EncodingOptions {Width = 115, Height = 65}
};
var imgBitmap = writer.Write(value);
```

imgBitmap is a instance of WriteableBitmap which is your image source in my opinion.

Comment: How can i improve the quality of the image generated? I have seen that the max Width and Height that I can put is 200, 130 beyond that it gives me Out of bound exception.

Comment: I can use higher values without errors. Which values did you try (width and height)? Which content did you encode? Please post a stacktrace of the exception.